# Spring Boot Application seems asleep after reboot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot Application. After daily restart of the apps, first request lasts 15 minutes to serve.

My Tomcat custom access logs are as follows:

```
000.000.0.0 - - [16/May/2017:09:25:03 +0200] -- [16/May/2017:09:09:34 +0200] - [16/May/2017:09:25:03 +0200] "GET /xxx/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - 929444 929.444 - 0
```

Request is received at 9:09:34 and its served at 9:25:03

This happens always after reboot.

The controller is serving only a *302 - Redirect*, in this example but this happens with all requests served dinamically. Static content is served right.

The application is running under **Spring Boot 1.4.1**

Comment: Springboot in general does lot of auto configuration that may not be needed. So you may want to narrow down only auto-configuration that is needed for your app. To see full list of auto-configuration included, just run logging of org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure in DEBUG mode. Ensure you set this property in application.properties. This might give you an info if there is additional auto config being done. Hope you have limited dependencies

Comment: Does it take a long time to start or it takes a long time to serve the first request. Do you see in the logs that springboot is up and running before the first request.

Comment: Spring boot is actually running, we'll check the autoconfigure...

Comment: The behaviour reproduces also after a couple of hours ! We are trying to put the TRACE mode for spring boot.